# How can I add to each element of a list a column with the column name/number of the minimum of 6 row values?

Tags: r, list, for-loop, apply, lapply

I have a list of 12000 elements. I want to add a column to each element in which the column name/number is displayed with a minimum of 6 row values. I can do this for a single element, but unfortunately not in a way that it works for all list elements.

Here is my code so far:

```
l2<-lapply(adresults_df_list, function(x) 
  cbind(x, bf = NA))

for(i in 1:12000){
adresults_df_list[[i]]$bf <- apply(adresults_df_list[[i]][,1:6], 1, function(x) which(x==min(x)))    
}
```

Mayby I can do this with lapply or a loop?

Comment: Without a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) it is difficult to answer what you are trying to ask.

Comment: Can you create a small example with 2-3 dataframes in a list where each dataframe has 4-5 rows and show expected output based on that?